# Printing based on an amount specified in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Spreadsheet
[image]

```vb
Sub OnePrint()
    Dim rngDocInfo As Range
    Dim objApp As Object, objDoc As Object
    Dim myPath As String

    Set rngDocInfo = Sheet5.Range("O18")
    myPath = UCase(rngDocInfo.Value2)

    If Len(Dir(myPath)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid filename. File does not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '~~> Get file extension and check if it is an Excel document
    If Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, ".")) Like "XLS*" Then
        Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set objDoc = objApp.Workbooks.Open(rngDocInfo.Value2)
        objApp.Visible = False
        objDoc.PrintOut
        objApp.Quit
        
    '~~> Get file extension and check if it is a Word document
    ElseIf Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, ".")) Like "DOC*" Then
        Set objApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set objDoc = objApp.Documents.Open(rngDocInfo.Value2)
        objApp.Visible = False
        objDoc.PrintOut
        objApp.Quit
        
    Else
        MsgBox "Unknown Document type"
    End If
End Sub
```

This code looks at a cell with a file directory leading to a document which is either Word or Excel, opens it, and then prints it.

Is it possible to print based on an amount specified in another cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see useful information is your image.

Add these lines to your code instead:

```
Dim ObjDoc As Object
Dim OutCopies As Integer

OutCopies = Sheet5.Range("A1").Value 'change your cell here

'Excel
ObjDoc.PrintOut Copies:=OutCopies

'Word
ObjDoc.PrintOut Copies:=OutCopies
```

Although it works with default format, it is convenient to check that the cell OutCopies format is number

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i realise now that i did not include the row or columns in my photo, I apologise for that, I have inputted the code as you suggested, but i get an error code saying "the number must be between 1 and 32765, try again by entering a number in this range"

Comment: Doesn't matter, i figured a way around that, Thank you very much.